# Facebook Messenger API: Buttons Not Showing On Mobile

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

Two pics say it all: Mobile instances of the chatbot show no buttons (regardless of `template_type` chosen -- button, generic, etc), but Desktop instances work fine. Buttons show up. Users naturally get quite confused and annoyed if they can't see the button they're supposed to be clicking and they instead start shouting at the bot.

Mobile Versions of Bot Shows No Buttons:

[image: Mobile Versions of Bot Shows No Buttons]

Desktop Versions of the Bot Do Show Buttons:

[image: Desktop Versions of the Bot Do Show Buttons]

There is a bug listed on the FB Dev forums that describes this behavior, a couple of them, but with not much action taking place, which makes me wonder if there isn't a workaround I don't know about. Is there?

Comment: Didn't experience that. Maybe you can update your post with the request you sent to Facebook ?

Comment: I am also having this issue, were you able to solve it? Do you also use messengerbot?

Comment: Users in a FB bot development group told me that Messenger API is not supported via the m.facebook.com domain -- only via the facebook.com (Desktop) domain and via the Messenger mobile apps. My bot has buttons on Desktop and in the Messenger apps, but does not if accessed via m.facebook.com. I can go to that domain from within any browser and see that my bot has no buttons. As users might try to access my bot in this way, for now, I send an initial warning that the bot does not work if accessed in a mobile browser and instead ask them to use the Desktop site or the dedicated Messenger apps.